# Pandas, convert datetime column to nearest specified 12th hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I want to be able to round an entire date column to whatever two 12hr times the values are closest to.

For example, if I want the column to be rounded to either 8am or 8pm.

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-28 15:25:22.456', '2022-01-27'])
```

Should become this

```
dates2 = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-28 20:00:00', '2022-01-27 08:00:00'])
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-28 20:00:00', '2022-01-27 08:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This was the solution I came up with thanks to other answers.

Here's a workable example.

```
from datetime import timedelta

step = timedelta(minutes=30)
start = datetime(2022,1,1,0,0,0)
end = datetime(2022,1,2,0,0,0)
seconds = (end - start).total_seconds()
array = []
for i in range(0, int(seconds), int(step.total_seconds())):
    array.append(start + timedelta(seconds=i))

dates = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(array))
```

Everything before 8am gets rounded up to 8am,
everything after is rounded up to 8pm. Anything after 8pm is rounded to 8am the next day.

```
dates2 = (dates-pd.Timedelta(hours=8)).dt.ceil('12H')+pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
pd.concat([dates,dates2],axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Rounding to nearest Hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561989/pandas-rounding-to-nearest-hour)

Comment: Below you will find an almost one line answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975428/11687201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round` and `pd.TimeDelta`:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime([
    '2022-01-28 15:25:22.456', 
    '2022-01-27'
])
dates.round('12H')+pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
```

Output like the requested output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-28 20:00:00', '2022-01-27 08:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Additional info:
Apart from `round` there are also `ceil` and `floor` methods available.

Edit:
In case the dates should get rounded to the closest time, different like the output above, as mentioned in the comments below this answer. This should work with the following:

```
(dates-pd.Timedelta(hours=8)).round('12H')+pd.Timedelta(hours=8)
```

Output would look like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-28 20:00:00', '2022-01-26 20:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: nice answer but I think your order of operations is wrong, currently `0:00` maps to `8:00`

Comment: @Matt As far as I can see from the question, mapping 0:00 to 8:00 is what was asked for.

Comment: Yep, just wanted the hours at 8:00 or 20:00 . I assume '2022-01-27' is treated as '2022-01-27 00:00:01'?

Comment: @golden_curry2020 fair enough if this does what you need! But the closest timestamp to 00:00:01 is actually 20:00:00 the day before

Comment: @Matt Whoops, I now understand what you meant. It started going into the next day

Comment: @Matt I added an option that addresses the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replace` to replace the nearest specific hour.

Change `first` and `second` to your preferred hour. In the code below, use `8` and `20`.

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2022-01-28 15:25:22.456', '2022-01-27'])

# round time to either 8am or 8pm
def round_time(time, first, second):
    if time.hour < 12:
        return time.replace(hour=first, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    else:
        return time.replace(hour=second, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

new_date = list()

for i in dates:
    # round time to either 8am or 8pm
    new_date.append(round_time(i, 8, 20))

new_dates = pd.to_datetime(new_date)
new_dates
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-28 20:00:00', '2022-01-27 08:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of a potential one line solution using .apply()?

Comment: should `if time.hour < 12` be changed to `if time.hour < 14`? otherwise `13:00 --> 20:00` but it should be `13:00 --> 8:00`